# How do you convert time difference to number in SSrs

Tags: time, reporting-services, numbers

Im trying to get the code to calculate time difference between clocking in and out for employees.

In the expression i typed (=Fields!Punched_Out.Value-Fields!Punched_In.Value) which give me the difference however the data is in time format such 2:30:00.

How can i convert 2:30:0 to number such as 2.5

thxs
sami

convert time to number

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF()` to calcuate the number of minutes, seconds or however accurate you need to be, then convert to hours (I assume) .

e.g.

```
=DATEDIFF("n", Fields!Punched_In.Value, Fields!Punched_Out.Value)/60
```

In this case "n" gets the difference in minutes, then just divide it by 60 to get it into hours. You can format the output to round the value using a format expression in the textbox.

MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datediff-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16